# Date field not sorting correctly in sql

Tags: mysql

Here are my search results (by cruise_date):

```
CRUISE_DATE     DAYS_TILL_CRUISE    NAME
10/13/2012  29  Octobertfest
10/20/2012  36  Rare Air Show,
10/20/2012  36  Bugs and Bratz
11/10/2012  57  Fall Color Super Cruise
11/10/2012  57  Club Cruise-In to Desoto State Park
9/22/2012   8   Bugs on the Bayou
9/23/2012   9   Hot Dogs and Hot Rods
```

Notice that the dates go October, November, September. 
This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT
         DATE_FORMAT(cruise_date, '%c/%e/%Y') AS cruise_date,
         DATEDIFF(cruise_date, CURDATE()) AS days_till_cruise,
         NAME
FROM
         `cruise`
WHERE
         `cruise_date` >= '2012-09-14'
ORDER BY

       `cruise_date`
```

Why won't my dates sort correctly?

[Click here to see this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baf28/5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It now sorts textually on the result of `DATE_FORMAT(cruise_date, '%c/%e/%Y')`, not on the field `cruise_date`. Try `ORDER BY cruise.cruise_date`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using same alias in `SELECT` clause. You need to change alias to something different or use `cruise.cruise_date` in `ORDER BY` clause, otherwise records would get sorted on text column from select. Try this:

```
SELECT
         DATE_FORMAT(cruise_date, '%c/%e/%Y') AS cruise_date_1,
         DATEDIFF(cruise_date, CURDATE()) AS days_till_cruise,
         NAME
FROM
         `cruise`
WHERE
         `cruise_date` >= '2012-09-14'
ORDER BY

       `cruise_date`
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baf28/13)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, try ordering it on `days_till_cruise`

```
ORDER BY
       `days_till_cruise`
```